# Communication between two StateObjects

Tags: swiftui, combine

Trying to establish asynchronous communication between two `StateObjects` inside one `View`, probably with `Combine` pipeline. Please note, `StateObjects` initialized with external dependendencies.

Any best practicies on this topic?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var objA: ObjectA
    @StateObject var objB: ObjectB

    init() {
        let unstableCommunicator = Communicator()

        self._objA = StateObject(
            wrappedValue: ObjectA(
                deps: .init(input: unstableCommunicator.inputA.eraseToAnyPublisher())
            )
        )
        self._objB = StateObject(
            wrappedValue: ObjectB(
                deps: .init(output: unstableCommunicator.outputB)
            )
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}

class Communicator: ObservableObject {
    let inputA = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    let outputB = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

    private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        outputB
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] msg in
                self?.inputA.send(msg)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellable)
    }
}

class ObjectA: ObservableObject {

    init(deps: Dependencies) {
        //Using deps.inputA
    }

    struct Dependencies {
        let input: AnyPublisher<Int, Never>
    }
}

class ObjectB: ObservableObject {

    init(deps: Dependencies) {
        //Using deps.outputB
    }

    struct Dependencies {
        let output: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

**What I tried:**

1 Using seperate `ObservableObject` for holding and connecting PasshroughSubjects.

This approach has init order disadvantage: if make `Communicator`  a StateObject, I cannot use it's subjects to init `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`.
I also tried to make `Communicator` `ObservedObject` and init it on higher level like this: `ContentView(communicator: .init())`. But in this case I can not to pass to `Communicator` any local `State` properties, like `@State var path: NavigationPath` to trigger navigation from it.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have updated the code to clearify my intention: **Combine connection between two StateObjects**

Comment: What have you tried? You could use: Combine, AsyncStreams, etc.

Comment: Delegates, protocols, …

Comment: Use dependency injection. Keep the view/presentation layer out of it.

Comment: @loremipsum, I'd like to do so, ContentView is some sort of Coordinator which making real presentation views with corresponding viewstores for keep Presentaiton layer clear of any logic.
Could you please dive a little into that idea?

Comment: @PtitXav could you please give an example of your idea?

Comment: @jnpdx, I have updated the post with details of what I have tried

Comment: You don't have to do everything in `init`. You can have Optionals and start observations on `didSet`.

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/

Comment: @jnpdx could you give code example?

Comment: @loremipsum I am using Swinject for DI. Still I can not see how to use it in this case, cause, as I said, `Communicator` depends on local `State` prop. Also, `Communicator` should have lifetime of `View` it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

`@StateObject` isn't designed for this, its for when you want to put a reference type in an `@State`, e.g. for doing something asynchronous (like a Combine pipeline) with the lifetime tied to a View struct that is actively being diffed because it represents something on screen. Your use case of updating properties doesn't require asynchronous so it isn't the right tool for the job.

This problem would be better solved with standard SwiftUI like the `View` struct's `body` func which is called when the params passed in are different from last time and that takes care of your change detection.

Dependencies in SwiftUI are best handled by passing them into the `View` struct's `init` or if its a shared controller/manager then use `EnvironmentKey`, like the built-in [authorizationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/authorizationcontroller). `State` and `StateObject` are sources of truth thus should have no dependencies because then they wouldn't be the source of truth.

If doing something asynchronous it would be much simpler to switch from Combine to async/await by using the `.task` and `.task(id:)` modifiers then you don't need any objects.

Comment: Lifetime of `objectA` and `objectB` tied to a `View`, they both doing something asynchronous, and they need a way to communicate with each other. My use case is to send and receive messages between two `StateObjects`, not to update properties.
I have updated the code to represent my intent.

Comment: If doing something asynchronous it would be much simpler to switch from Combine to async/await by using `.task` and `.task(id:)` modifiers then you don't need any objects.

Answer (score 0):

Simple dependencies with protocole :

```
protocol Dependencies {
    func set(firstProperty: Int)
    func set(secondProperty: Int)
}

class ObjectA: ObservableObject {
    var dependencies: Dependencies?
    @Published var a: Int = 11
    @Published var b: Int = 22
    
    init(deps: Dependencies? = nil) {
        //Configure objects on dependencies
        self.dependencies = deps
    }
    
    // Each time you set A it call dependence on firstProperty
    func set(newA: Int) {
        a = newA
        dependencies?.set(firstProperty: a)
    }
    
    // Each time you set B it call dependence on seondProperty
    func set(newB: Int) {
        b = newB
        dependencies?.set(secondProperty: b)
    }
}
extension ObjectA: Dependencies {
    func set(firstProperty: Int) {
        // pay attention to not call set(newA) to prevent code loop
        a = firstProperty
    }

    func set(secondProperty: Int) {
        // pay attention to not call set(newB) to prevent code loop
        b = secondProperty
    }
    
}

class ObjectB: ObservableObject {
    var dependencies: Dependencies?
    @Published var c: Int = 33
    @Published var d: Int = 44
    
    init(deps: Dependencies? = nil) {
        //Configure objects on dependencies
        self.dependencies = deps
    }
    
    func set(newC: Int) {
        c = newC
        dependencies?.set(firstProperty: c)
    }
    
    func set(newD: Int) {
        d = newD
        dependencies?.set(secondProperty: d)
    }
}
extension ObjectB: Dependencies {
    func set(firstProperty: Int) {
        c = firstProperty
    }
    
    func set(secondProperty: Int) {
        d = secondProperty
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var objA = ObjectA()
    @StateObject var objB = ObjectB()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ObjectA a:\(objA.a) b:\(objA.b)")
            HStack {
                Button {
                    objA.set(newA: objA.a + 1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Increase a")
                }
                Button {
                    objA.set(newB: objA.b + 1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Increase b")
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Button {
                    objB.set(newC: objB.c + 1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Increase c")
                }
                Button {
                    objB.set(newD: objB.d + 1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Increase d")
                }
            }
            Text("ObjectB c:\(objB.c) d:\(objB.d)")

        }
        .onAppear() {
            //init communication between objA and objB
            objA.dependencies = objB
            objB.dependencies = objA
            objA.set(newA: 11)
            objA.set(newB: 22)
        }
    }
}
```